# Error building default Native-Activity Android Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk, cross-platform

I am attempting to build the default project that is generated in VS 2015 for template type **Cross Platform -> Native-Activity Application (Android)** but immediately receive an error during build:

Output:

> 2>  **BUILD FAILED**
>
> 2>  C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\tools\ant\build.xml:538:
>   **Unable to resolve project target 'android-19'** :

Application Manifest:

The ApplicationManifest.xml file has the following settings:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

VS Options

Tools -> Options -> Cross Platform -> C++ -> **Android SDK**, **Android NDK** and **Java SE Development Kit** paths have been updated to match the settings I used successfully in Android Studio (for a different but equally simple native project).  And the fourth path **Apache Ant** points to the newest version I just installed:

- **SDK 6.0 (API Level 23)**
- **JDK 8.0**
- **Ant 1.9.6**

I have extensive VS experience (C# / C++) and good (but rusty) experience with Android/Java but no experience using VS to build for Android.

I am confused by the error in general, but am particularly confused because of the API level **19**.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Im not familiar with VS2015 , do you have an Applination.mk file? If so open it and take a look at the APP_PLATFORM

Comment: Good suggestion, Vitaly, but no, there is not an application.mk.  After researching APP_PLATFORM it did get me thinking that there must be something similar somewhere (which I found; answered below).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  When the Visual Studio solution is generated there are two projects added: [name].NativeActivity (C++) and [name].Packaging (Java).

Both project's properties allow **Target API Level** to be defined.  Repeat these steps for both projects:

Solution Explorer > Right-click project (not solution) > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Target API Level